# Salesforce Authenticator not working, how to fix this?

Tags: authentication, login, login-errors, multi-factor-authentication

My Salesforce Authenticator is not getting any request for approval and it gets directly denied. I could not try the code route too as that is also not working. Please help. Let me know if there are any other ways to login.
[image: Pic of the access denied without me getting a request in my mobile app]

[image: Getting an invalid code after entering the code]

Comment: We got excatly the same freaking problem. Users cannot login 3 days ago.(2022-1015~) we still cannot figure out why.
Is this maybe a problem related with come up with Salesforce win23 update? Please someone help with this!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the cause of the problem. I was able to do a work around, by asking my Lead to reset the Temporary Verification Code in  the User Detail Page and then login using that. Then I had disconnected Salesforce Authenticator currently and will reset it when I find time.